Numbered templates (for theorems) in MediaWiki
I am setting up a MediaWiki instance that will in particular contain mathematical material. I want to write a template for theorems, with the two following properties:

The theorems are automatically numbered. This numbering should be dynamic: if an edition inserts a theorem between Theorems 1 and 2, the latter should become Theorem 3.
The theorems can be referred to: I want a piece of code that produces "Theorem 2", given an identifier of the second theorem of the page. (Which means that the template for theorems should be given this identifier as a parameter.)

Basically, I want an equivalent of LaTeX's theorem environment and of its \ref command. I'm asking for a template, but mere templates may not be powerful enough, in which case any alternative is appreciated.
Do you have any hints of what is the best way to achieve this?

As pointed out by @Alexander Mashin, there is no hope for a solution using MediaWiki's embedded Lua engine. In the end I relied on this answer
and did the following.
First a template for theorems.
A parameter id is stored in a data-theoremid attribute of the container. As an (unnecessary) enhancement, I did the same for a parameter type allowing for different theorem types: Theorem, Lemma, etc.
<div class="theorembox {{{type}}}" data-theoremid="{{{id}}}" data-theoremtype="{{{type}}}">
<div class="theoremhead">
<span class="theoremtype">{{ucfirst:{{{type}}}}}</span>&nbsp;<span class="theoremcount"></span>
{{#if:{{{title|}}}|<span class="theoremtitle">({{{title}}})</span>|}}
</div>
{{{content}}}
</div>

The usage is {{Theorem box|id=mytheorem|type=Theorem|title=Fermat's last theorem|content=For all n≥3, ...}}.
Second a template for references.
The identifier of the referred theorem is given as {{{1}}}.
<span class="theoremref" data-referto="{{{1}}}">[[#theorem:{{{1}}}|<span class="theoremtype"></span>&nbsp;<span class="theoremcount"></span>]]</span>

The usage is {{Theorem ref|mytheorem}}.
Then two JavaScript functions
The first one looks for theorems and numbers them (storing, for each identifier, the corresponding theorem type and number); the second one looks for reference calls and fills them. I put these functions in MediaWiki:Common.js.
var theorems = {};

document.querySelectorAll('.theorembox').forEach((el,i) => {
    var id = el.getAttribute('data-theoremid').replace(/\s/g, "_");
    var type = el.getAttribute('data-theoremtype');
    var number = i+1;
    el.setAttribute('id', 'theorem:' + id);
    el.querySelector('.theoremcount').innerHTML = number;
    theorems[id] = {type:type, number:number};
});

document.querySelectorAll('.theoremref').forEach((el,i) => {
    var id = el.getAttribute('data-referto').replace(/\s/g, "_");
    var href = '#theorem:' + id;
    var type = theorems[id].type;
    var number = theorems[id].number;
    el.querySelector('a').setAttribute('href', href);
    el.querySelector('.theoremtype').innerHTML = type.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + type.slice(1);
    el.querySelector('.theoremcount').innerHTML = number;
});


If you want to number entities in a wikipage (other than automatic numbering of headings for users, or <ol> tag generated by # wiki markup and converted to numbered list by client browser), you ought to provide that number as a parametre of your template for theorem definiton — just as of the template that generates a wikilink to it.
You cannot get stable automatic numbering of entities on a wikipage, because the order, in which different parts of a wikipage are parsed, is not guaranteed anymore.

Wow, even though I understand the benefits of parallelization this seems to be quite a brutal feature. :-o Isn't there a standard workaround, e.g. using Javascript? It seems to me that wanting to maintain a global counter may be needed by many people.

This is achievable, you have to do it by combining MediaWiki templates and the #invoke function, allowing you to use Lua scripts to generate the dynamic content.
Here are the steps.
1. create a Lua module
create a page in your Mediawiki instance, e.g Module:TheoremCounter, with the following Lua code:
local theoremCounter = {}

function theoremCounter.increment()
    local count = tonumber(mw.loadData('TheoremCounter', 'count'))
    if count == nil then
         count = 0
    end
    count = count + 1
    mw.saveData('TheoremCounter', 'count', tostring(count))
    return count
end

function theoremCounter.getLabel(id)
    local count = tonumber(mw.loadData('TheoremCounter', 'count'))
    local label = 'Theorem ' .. tostring(count)
    if id ~= nil then
        label = label .. ' (' .. id .. ')'
    end
    return label
end

return theoremCounter

the code uses the mw.loadData and mw.saveData functions to store and retrieve a counter value. The increment function increments the counter and returns the new one.
2. create a template for theorems
create a template like this Template:Theorem, with the below code
{{#invoke:TheoremCounter|increment}}
<div class="theorem">
  <span class="theorem-label">{{#invoke:TheoremCounter|getLabel|{{{id}}}}}</span>
  {{{content}}}
</div>

The template uses the #invoke function to call the increment and getLabel function from the Lua module.
3. Template referencing theorems
create template for reference 'Template:RefTheorem'
{{#invoke:TheoremCounter|getLabel|{{{id}}}}}

Usage
To use the templates, it's very simple, just create a new page and add the following code.
{{Theorem|id=MyTheorem|content=This is my theorem.}}

and dynamic label to follow the code
{{RefTheorem|id=MyTheorem}}

The above example I created only for the simple incrementing counter, which may not be suitable for all cases. But it's a good start.

Thank you very much for your help! Unfortunately the templates only render errors: Lua error in package.lua at line 80: module 'TheoremCounter' not found. Do you have an idea of how to fix this? (Also, I guess a }} is missing in Template:Theorem.)

The issue might be the module name and location, can you check and make sure the Lua module is named TheoremCounter.lua and is located in the Module namespace on your MediaWiki wiki. The module should be at the page Module:TheoremCounter.

Yes, this is the case.

You could use CSS.
Add to MediaWiki:Common.css:
.mw-parser-output {
    counter-reset: css-counter 0;
}

.mw-parser-output .numbered {
    counter-increment: css-counter 1;
}

.mw-parser-output .numbered:before {
    content: counter(css-counter) ". ";
}

Use the class .numbered in a template:
<includeonly><{{{2|div}}} class="numbered">{{{1}}}</{{{2|div}}}></includeonly><noinclude>Add a numbered tag. Parametres:
# tag contents
# tag type (default: <code>div</code>).

== Examples ==
{| class="wikitable"
! Wikitext !! Result
|-
| <code><nowiki>Some text.

{{numbered|First.}}

More text.

{{numbered|Second.}}</nowiki></code>
| Some text.

{{numbered|First.}}

More text.

{{numbered|Second.}}
|}
</noinclude>


This would produce numbered items indeed, but I'm afraid it is impossible to use only CSS for the second part of the question (referencing these numbers), the content of ::before is not part of the DOM.
